# How to use scripts on relay response url?

Tags: css, authorize.net

I'm trying to style my relay response URL for A.Net, but the URL is still showing "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" so my CSS files are not being included. Right now it just looks like an ugly plain HTML page.

Do I have to pass along the response code and other POST information to another script on my server in order to include the styling?

Answer (score 0):

Relay Response loads your page as a pass-through (Authnet reads the contents of your page and sends them to the user). This means if you must either use the full URL (e.g. including the protocol and domain name) in the path to your CSS file or put the CSS directly in the web page.

Comment: I've already tried the absolute path with: http://www.example/example/example.css, and it did not work.

Comment: That's not the full URL.

Comment: I meant to put the domain as well, it seems stack overflow didn't add it in. The in-line way works, but as you can guess that's not very good design.